# How to make an array of matrix (of varying sizes)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get to grips with matlab, so this question is more about syntax than anything else.

I want to create a vector (1xn) of matrices. The matrices are all possibly of different dimensions eg. matrix 1 = 4 x 5, matrix 2 = 5 x 6 etc.

I tried using a for loop, but I had the following error:

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: You can use [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store an array of matrices of different sizes as a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) of matrices. Often you'll want to create these cell arrays dynamically using the [arrayfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) function which will do this for you if you set the `UniformOutput` option to `0`.

**Example:**

```
cols = [4 5 6];
rows = [1 2 3];
A = arrayfun(@(i) zeros(rows(i),cols(i)),1:3,'UniformOutput',0);
A{:}
```

Outputs:

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0


ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```